# Parse error when setting header to HTTP status in PHP

Tags: php

I can not figure out what is going wrong but on this simple PHP below, I am getting parse errors.

I am getting this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in E:\Server\htdocs\myframework\library\api\rest-test\index.php on line 3
```

on this code

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); 
header('Content-type: application/json');

$data = 'testing dgdg dfgdf gdf';// my code that returns the appropriate data;

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

However when I swap out `header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');` for `header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');`  then the error goes away.  Please help me understand this.  Testing on Windows with XAMPP

---

**RESOLVED**

My original code had a blank space at the end of the `header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');` line, removed that space and everything works as expected now.

Comment: I don't get your error. I tetsted your code on windows and linux. Both tests worked properly without any errors.

Comment: what if you try sending the header with no echo? what if you try ***header("Status: 404 Not Found");*** ? which php version are you using?

Comment: Using PHP Version 5.3.6, it appears I might be using FastCGI and didn't even know it as `header("Status: 404 Not Found");` does work.  Just weird how when I change 404 to 200 on the original header how that works as well

Comment: The code you provided won't ever cause an 'unexpected T_STRING' error.

Comment: FIXED: WEird, there was a blank space at the end of the line `header('Content-type: application/json');` that caused it, I removed this weird EOL space and it worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should consider using `header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not Found");` instead of `header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');` owing to the fact that your underlying server might be using different HTTP Protocols and this will keep you from having to update it later.

Second, I suspect the issue is stemming from the Content Header you are adding to the section. Try removing `header('Content-type: application/json');` and see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: Eventually I tried removing everything except the `header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');` line and the error changed to something about the EOL, I then realized there was a space after that line, removed that space and now it works.  I had copied that line off the php docs so must have something to do with linux vs windows EOL

Comment: That would do it. Any white space or characters being sent that are not a part of the proper header sequence will break it if you attempt to do another header() entry after the characters have been sent.

Comment: Thanks, that is deffinately good to know, actualyl it's something I have known but just 1 space is hard to spot.  I like the idea of using `$_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL`

Answer (score 1):

Nope; [that testcase is fine](http://codepad.org/ohAJABhE).

The error comes from your original code, not your testcase, and you failed to reproduce the issue in your testcase. So we can't identify it...

Comment: See my comments above, you are correct, it was something on my original code, a blank space

Answer (score 0):

If you use FCGI, could you change your 404 line to `header("Status: 404 Not Found");`. Maybe this helps.